# How to minimize two functions at the same time with common variables

Tags: python, scipy, minimization, fixed-point-iteration, root-finding

I am trying to find the roots of three equations, and currently I am using `minimize` from `scipy`.

```
from scipy.optimize import basinhopping
import numpy as np

def get_attraction(b1,b2, b3):
    c1 = 20 * b1 + 12 * b2 + 6 * b3
    c2 = 12 * b1 + 24 * b2 + 18 * b3
    c3 = 0 * b1 + 14 * b2 + 30 * b3
    return c1,c2,c3

def get_prob(x, s1, s2, s3, a, lamda, t1, t2, t3):
    p1, p2 = x[0], x[1]
    p3 = 1 - p1 - p2

    b1 = s1 * (1-a) + p1 * a
    b2 = s2 * (1-a) + p2 * a
    b3 = s3 * (1-a) + p3 * a

    c1,c2,c3=get_attraction(b1,b2,b3)

    a1 = c1+t1
    a2 = c2+t2
    a3 = c3+t3

    nom1 = np.exp(lamda*a1)
    nom2 = np.exp(lamda*a2)
    nom3 = np.exp(lamda*a3)
    dem = nom1 + nom2 + nom3

    p1_t = nom1 / dem
    p2_t = nom2 / dem
    p3_t = nom3 / dem

    return (p1_t - p1)**2+(p2_t - p2)**2+(p3_t - p3)**2

s1=1.0
s2=0.0
s3=0.0
a=1.0
lamda=-20
t1=30.0
t2=30.0
t3=30.0
result = basinhopping(get_prob, x0=[0.0, 0.25], niter=50, seed=np.random.seed(0),interval=10,
                              minimizer_kwargs={'args': (s1,s2,s3,a,lamda,t1,t2,t3),
                                                'method': "SLSQP",
                                                'tol': 1.0e-5,
                                                'bounds': [(0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 1.0)],
                                                'constraints': {'type': 'ineq',
                                                                'fun': lambda x: 1 - x[0] - x[1],
                                                                'jac': lambda x: np.full_like(x, -1)}})

print(result)

                    message: ['requested number of basinhopping iterations completed successfully']
                    success: True
                        fun: 1.646140610988733
                          x: [ 4.722e-02  9.926e-02]
                        nit: 50
      minimization_failures: 36
                       nfev: 2401
                       njev: 353
 lowest_optimization_result: message: Optimization terminated successfully
                             success: True
                              status: 0
                                 fun: 1.646140610988733
                                   x: [ 4.722e-02  9.926e-02]
                                 nit: 23
                                 jac: [-3.613e+00 -1.509e+00]
                                nfev: 164
                                njev: 23
```

Essentially, I want to find `p1`, `p2`, `p3` (probability which should sum up to 1) such that `p1=p1_t`, `p2=p2_t`, `p3=p3_t`.
Sometimes I got pretty large `result.fun` which is not so good for the root-finding problem.

I have also tried to use `root` and `fixed_point`. They perform worse than `minimization`.

Is there a way to minimize two functions at the time to improve the precision but without increase `niter`? Increasing number of iteration takes a long time, and it is not ideal for me.

Comment: Have you tried `least_squares` (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html)? That is probably well suited to your problem.

Comment: Also, if you can define all the variables, like `s1`, etc... so that the code is executable, I can provide an executable example.

Comment: @MattHaberland I've just edited with an example

Comment: Oops, I didn't notice that you had constraints, and `least_squares` doesn't handle that. I think `minimize` or one of the global optimizers is your best bet. To reduce execution time, you could consider providing the objective function gradient and/or Hessian. I think `slsqp` and `trust-constr` are the only real options with nonlinear constraints. (I've not had good luck with COBYLA.)

Comment: With `lambda = -20` the variable `dem` become drastically small and ends up to be `nan`. Is this setting correct ?

Comment: @jlandercy Yes, it is possible, and `lambda` can also be infinity actually. It is part of another optimizaton, but it actually never happened, in my complete code, I use `logsumexp` to transform the calculation.